# Application unable auto detect device screen size

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I had developed an application. I done 2 sets of layout which were

> default and small

So i have 2 layout folders which were res/layout and res/layout-small.

I tested in emulator which was 2.7in HVGA it does auto use the res/layout-small folder.

When i run it on device, it does not but still using res/layout.

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="480"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="480" >
</supports-screens>
```

Why the application once installed into device and unable to detect device screen size?

Comment: What Android versions are running on the emulator and the device. What device are you using ?

Comment: @bitbox, sorry for late reply, my emulator is using 1.6 and it able to auto detect. My device is using 2.2.3 but unable to detect screen size. However, my another device nexus is running 4.0.3 and it able to detect too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> **Note**: These minimum screen sizes were not as well defined prior to
>   Android 3.0, so you may encounter some devices that are mis-classified
>   between normal and large. These are also based on the physical
>   resolution of the screen, so may vary across devices—for example a
>   1024x720 tablet with a system bar actually has a bit less space
>   available to the application due to it being used by the system bar.

If you aren't using a 3.0+ device, then this could be a problem with the device.